# ActionScript 3 Looping

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I just started using Looping in AS3 recently and I have much to learn. here is the question. Below is a Loop that puts 5 balls one on top of the other on the stage. So far so good. however, I'd like to create a situation when clicking on a button, the bottom ball is removed, and then each  ball take the place of the ball below it one by one, continue this for each click until all the balls are gone. .  I have created this situation with add/remove child and I thought it could be more efficient with looping. I just don't know how to access the balls since I don't have instance name or class name that I can reference too.

```
var ball: gBall4M;
var i: Number;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  ball = new gBall4M();
  ball.x = 331.30;
  ball.y = 25 + i * 17
  addChild(ball);
}
function release2Ball2(event: MouseEvent): void {
```

This is the effect I want to get https://youtu.be/B4GLolw8QVA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer of @daniel-messer, you can use an [`Array`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html) to store your balls, and for the second part of your question, when removing the last ball and moving the other ones, you can use [`array.pop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#pop()) to remove the last element of the array, and then you can use [`array.map()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#map()) to move the other balls :

```
function release2Ball2(event:MouseEvent): void
{
    if(balls.length > 0){
        ball = balls.pop();             // remove and get the last element of the array
        ball.parent.removeChild(ball);  // remove that element from the DisplayObjectContainer 
        function move_ball(item:Ball, index:int, array:Array):void {
            item.y += 17;
        }
        // move the rest of elements
        balls.map(move_ball, this);
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Take a look on the code working, I added numbers to understand how balls are moving :

[image]

Your full code can be like this :

```
var balls:Array = [],
    ball:gBall4M;

for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ball = new gBall4M();
    ball.x = 331.30;
    ball.y = 25 + i * 17;
    balls.push(ball);
    addChild(ball);
}

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release2Ball2);
function release2Ball2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (balls.length > 0) {
        ball = balls.pop();
        ball.parent.removeChild(ball);
        function move_ball(item:gBall4M, index:int, array:Array):void {
            item.y +=  17;
        }
        balls.map(move_ball, this);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

To do that kind of animation, you can use a `Timer` like this :

```
var balls:Array = [],
    ball:gBall4M;

for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ball = new gBall4M();
    ball.x = 30;
    ball.y = 25 + i * 17;
    balls.push(ball);
    addChild(ball);
}

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release2Ball2);
function release2Ball2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (balls.length > 0) {
        ball = balls.pop();
        ball.parent.removeChild(ball);
        if(balls.length > 0){
            timer.start();
        }
    }
}

var timer:Timer = new Timer(150);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent){
        if(balls.length >= timer.currentCount){
            balls[balls.length - timer.currentCount].y += 17;
        } else {
            timer.reset();
        }
    })
```

Which will give you something like this :

[image]

Hope that can help.

Comment: I am not working with code file. This is what works as far as removing the bottom balls one at a time. Still need to code balls dropping, any idea?

`var ball: gBall4M;
var i: Number;
var ballA: Array = [];

buttonA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release2Ball2);
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 ball = new gBall4M();
 ball.x = 331.30;
 ball.y = 100 + i * 17
 addChild(ball);
 ballA.push(ball);
}
function release2Ball2(event: MouseEvent): void {
 if (ballA.length > 0) {
  ball = ballA.pop();
  removeChild(ball);
  ball = null
  for (i = 0; i < ballA.length; i++) {
   ballA[i].y - 17;`

Comment: @SBA What's your problem exactly ? Did you tried my code ?

Comment: Yes tried your code. it didn't work. the code above works but not entirely. I want that after each click after the bottom ball have been removed, the remaining balls will drop one step down.

Comment: @SBA It's weird, because that's exactly what my code did ! You have to use my code as it is ( with the `balls.map()` ) or edit your code : `balls[i].y += 17;`.

Comment: I appreciate all the effort you are making to help me but it Still not working for me. Lets go back to the basics. I do not work with class file I code directly on the timeline. @daniel-messer code does not work on the timeline. I'm assuming that your code is just another version of his. I tried to use your code with my code on the timeline unsuccessfully. the code I posted above. works on the timeline but only to the point it removes the balls but doesn't preposition them.  I see how yours works exactly the way I want it but I can't get the code to work in my environment.

Comment: @SBA I edited my answer and added the full code, take a look.

Comment: I get it. the cod is correct and does exactly as described. but the effect is wrong because it appears as if the top ball gets deleted. I need kind of a delay mechanism. any Idea?

Comment: @SBA What do you mean ? Some kind of animation ?

Comment: I just added a link to youtube I made that shows what I want to get. look it up and let me know. I did it with a strait code. I want to replicated using looping https://youtu.be/B4GLolw8QVA

Comment: That is great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the instances inside an array or similar that you can use later.

I hope you are using a code file and not writing the code directly inside a frame inside the flash editor. Otherwise you might end up with issues.

Something similar to this should work

```
package {
  class Main {
    var balls:Array = [];

    function createBalls() {
      var ball: gBall4M;
      var i: Number;

      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        ball = new gBall4M();
        ball.x = 331.30;
        ball.y = 25 + i * 17;
        balls.push(ball); //Save them to array
        addChild(ball);
      }
    }

    function release2Ball2(event: MouseEvent): void {
      var clickedBall:gBall4M = event.currentTarget as gBall4M; //this might be wrong depending on what you are listening for, and what type of object gBall4M is...
      for(var i=0; i<balls.length; ++i) {
        if(balls[i] == clickedBall) {
          balls[i].splice(i, 1); //remove instance from array
          removeChild(clickedBall); //remove instance from display list
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Might wanna remove that underscore in your declaration variable

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out.  using this code on frame 1

```
function release2Ball2(event: MouseEvent): void {
  if (ballA.length > 0) {
  ball = ballA.pop();
  removeChild(ball);
  ball = null
  gotoAndPlay(2);

  }
}
stop();
```

using this code on frame 10:

```
for (i = 0; i < ballA.length; i++) {
  ballA[i].y += 17;
stop();
```

That does the trick.

Thank you so much for your help